# How to translate "add" as in "add me on Skype"?

Tags: verb, english-to-german

How to translate the "add" when talking about social networks?

> Please add me on Skype.
>
> I'll add you on Facebook.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Frankly speaking, the most common word you say is "*[adden](http://szenesprachenwiki.de/definition/adden/)*". If you want to be a bit more formal, or try to avoid the English word, I'd go with "*hinzufügen*".

The alternative is to use the word "*einladen*" which means "*to invite*", or to use the substantive "*Einladung*".

> Adde mich doch bitte in Facebook/Skype.
>
> Kann ich dich zu meiner Freundesliste hinzufügen?
>
> Schickst du mir ne Einladung/Freundschaftsanfrage?
>
> Ich lad dich noch heute Abend ein.

Of course, there is indeed one way to avoid the problem:

> A: Bist du eigentlich bei Facebook?
>
> B: Ja, klar.
>
> A: Wie finde ich dich denn?
>
> B: Mein vollständiger Name ist ...
>
> A: Super, dann schaue ich nachher mal, ob ich dich finde.

Comment: Thanks. Is _adden_ at the same level of informality as _to add_?

Comment: @TimN Yes, I think so.

Comment: Ädden ist ja nun wirklich häßlich.

Comment: @TimN Regarding the discussion about the word "adden". Note: This word **is used** in common German. It doesn't matter if it sounds awkward to "outsiders". It is the term of the users of fb, g+, etc. It's not slang, it's not just used by some wannabes or juveniles, etc. Far from it! I, personally, would even go so far to say that you can use the word in essays, then of course in quotation marks and with a hint and an explanation what it means and where it comes from and why it is acceptable. Only if the audience is conservative I would prefer "hinzufügen".

Comment: @userunknown: das ist eine Frage Geschmacks. Dass es gebräuchlich ist, ist dagegen ein [Fakt](https://www.google.de/search?hl=en&as_q=adden&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=lang_de&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&tbs=&as_filetype=&as_rights=#q=%22adden%22&hl=en&lr=lang_de&as_qdr=all&tbs=lr:lang_1de&prmd=imvns&ei=zWfIT-2gB-z34QSmqZEo&start=20&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=e5439a9c66e465e3&biw=1366&bih=682).

Comment: Das kommt auf Alter, Bildung und Kultur an. In meinem Umfeld ist es nicht gebräuchlich. Dabei würde ich mein Umfeld gar nicht als elitär bezeichnen.

Comment: Actually *adden* is even less formal than *to add*. I'd go with *adden* on facebook and with *hinzufügen* on xing/linkedin et cetera.

Comment: I'd rather say "adden" is extremely informal, and probably restricted to youth language. I don't think I have ever heard anyone use it. Maybe I am too old for this word at roughly 30, but I would strongly advise against using it in any written text. Also, I think it is *never* used in German translations of user interfaces of any popular instant messenging or social networking services - they all use "zur Kontaktliste hinzufügen", "in die Kontaktliste aufnehmen", etc.

Comment: Fun fact. This answer received 3 downvotes in a few hours...It had not a single one in over 3 years. At least the last downvoter explained his reasoning. However, @O.R.Mapper We are the same age and I hear (and use) adden all the time, when talking about Facebook. It is the most common verb, and also used by older people. Just yesterday I overheard a woman about 45 at the cash desk using this word. Your suggestion are really very formal and are never used when talking. Yes, in a help site it's the appropriate wording, but OPs sentence doesn't sound like that. It's an example of oral language.

Comment: @Em1: Informally, I know statements like "Machst/Tust du mich in dein Facebook rein?", and anglicisms are used, as well: "Schickst du mir 'nen Facebook-Request?" It is only "Addest du mich in Facebook?" which I have never encountered. Maybe it is more usual in the North or so, and only rather unused down here in the South-West? With that said, in my experience, "Fügst du mich in/bei Facebook hinzu?" is used all the time, also when talking.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Both examples you mentioned are "gestellt". Who the hell would say that? An uneducated foreign speaker "Tust du mich mal rein.." Sorry, but that must be a joke. — I live in Western Germany, i.e. above the Main-Linie. So yes, maybe it's different in the south. And perhaps, say, Austrian people say even something completely different then. Don't know. But if we're talking about regional differences, I think we don't need to discuss at all.

Comment: @Em1: "Sorry, but that must be a joke." - it's not. It's colloquial German by native speakers. Indeed, possibly a regional variant that is not used in other places, but the same apparently applies to "adden".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper This would be something for http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de ;)

Answer (score 8):

There is no real good translation because the best word "hinzufügen" is transitive in german while "to add" is intransitive in english.

The correct translation of "to add" is either `addieren` which is only used in context of mathematics: `Ich addiere eins zu zwei und erhalte drei` (`I add one to two and get three`), or `hinzufügen` which is used in all other situations.

The problem is: `hinzufügen` is a transitive Verb. So when you use "hinzufügen", then you must say to what you are adding something. The english `to add` is intransitive. There is no need to say to what you are adding something.

### example

> I add Tom.

This sentence is complete in english, but it contains not enough information to be translated into correct german. You have no information to what Tom is added here.

In german you would say:

> Ich füge Tom meinen Kontakten hinzu.

(Watch how `hinzufügen` is splitted into `füge` and `hinzu`).
This sentence translated into english gives:

> I add Tom to my contacts.

But `to my contacts` was missing in the first sentence, and so it could not be translated 1:1.

### other examples

> Please add me on Skype.
>   Please add me on Google+.

You say on what platform you want to be added (on Skype or Google+), but you don't tell to what you want to be added (to your friends contacts or circles). So this sentence can not be translated into correct german as it is.

Correct german sentences would be:

> Bitte füge mich auf Skype deinen Kontakten hinzu.
>   Bitte füge mich auf Google+ einem deiner Kreise hinzu.

Which gives in english:

> Please add me to your contacts on Skype.
>   Please add me to one of your circles on Google+.

---

To avoid the problem of the missing destination of the adding-process, young digital citicens invented the word `adden` which can be used the same way as `to add` in english:

> Ich adde Tom.
>   Bitte adde mich auf Skype.
>   Bitte adde mich auf Google+.

But `adden` is only known to young digital citicens. I am 47 years old. It feels strange to me and most other people in my age to use this word. I know this word, but I don't use it. Many people older then 30 don't even know `adden`.

Comment: Young digital citizens invented nothing, but used what they failed to translate as if it where a german verb. `Bitte füg mich auf Skype hinzu` - wieso kann man das nicht sagen/übersetzen? Auch bestreite ich die Aussage, dass 'addieren' nur im mathematischen Kontext benutzt wird, bzw. dass das hinzufügen zu Listen ein nichtmathematischer Kontext ist.

Comment: Warum ist die korrekte Überestzung für "to add" entw. "addieren" oder in allen anderen Situationen "hinzufügen"? Das stimmt nicht, siehe [leo](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=add). Es gibt einfach nicht DIE Übersetzung schlechthin.

Comment: Warum kann "I add Tom" nicht mit "Ich füg Tom hinzu" übersetzt werden? In einer Unterhaltung, wo der Bezungspunkt bereits klar ist, kann man die Angabe doch problemlos fallen lassen. Ist der Bezugspunkt nicht klar, würdest du selbst im Englischen nachfragen. Außerdem kannst du doch auch z.b. sagen: "Ich gehe morgen ins Kino", fügte sie hinzu. ("Tomorrow I go to the cinema", she added).

Comment: Man kann sich darüber streiten, ob eine Aussage wie "Ich füg dich in Skype hinzu" semantisch falsch oder richtig ist, aber der Bezug ist auch hier klar (natürlich zur Freundesliste/Kontakten, wo auch sonst!!!) und ansich als wortgetreue Übersetzung vollkommen akzeptabel.

Comment: Das Wort "adden" ist nicht nur jungen Menschen bekannt, sondern allen, die sich mit der Materie Computer und Technik in irgendeiner Form beschäftigen. Das Durchschnittsalter in der Firma in der ich arbeite ist um die 50 und fast jeder kennt den Begriff adden, doch haben nur etwa 10% einen eigenen G+/Fb-Account.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Bin etwas überrascht wegen transitiv/intransitiv... soweit ich es sehe, funktionieren die beiden Wörter ziemlich exakt gleich: beide haben mindestens ein direktes Objekt (das hinzugefügt wird) und ggf. ein indirektes (dem das direkte Obj. hinzugefügt wird). Beide sind also transitiv, oder? (Die einzige Ausnahme wäre "to add" im Sinne von "my daughter already can add and subtract")

Comment: @Em1: Falsch. Ich bin Informatiker, um die 30, Nutzer zahlreicher Instant-Messenging-Dienste und kannte es nicht - was auch impliziert, dass es wohl keiner meiner Kontakte so verwendet. Vielleicht liegt es daran, dass die Menschen mit Durchschnittsalter 50 mit erhöhter Wahrscheinlichkeit auch Kinder im Teenager-Alter in der Verwandtschaft haben, von woher sie das Wort kennen?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ich hab's schon im anderen Kommentar geschrieben. Warum das Wort nicht kennst, kann ich nicht sagen. Das Wort wird so verdammt viel verwendet, dass ich inzw. — 3 Jahre nach der ursprünglichen Frage — meine Antwort so formulieren würde: "Die Übersetzung lautet 'Adden'. Keine Alternativen." Klingt brutal, ist aber meine Erfahrung.

Answer (score 1):

- füg mich hinzu
- nimm mich auf
- trag mich ein
- inkludiere mich
- mach mich zu Deinem ... bei ...
- setz mich auf Deine Kontaktliste/Freundesliste

Comment: Well, all of them could be conceivable translations, but only one of those is used in practice and all other sounds ugly (uglier then "adden"!). ... Warum mit aller Gewalt versuchen eine Übersetzung zu finden, wenn die Alltagssprache adden verwendet?

Comment: Vielleicht verwendest Du in der Alltagssprache "adden" - ich sicher nicht. Adden und zu adden? Ich habe geaddet, ich werde adden, ich bin geaddet worden? In einen Freundeskreis hinzufügen/aufnehmen, in eine Liste eintragen - welche der Formen hälst Du denn für die einzig übliche? Und: Suchen wir hier nicht - außer es wird ausdrücklich verlangt - nach gutem Deutsch?

Comment: Also "inkludiere mich" hört sich arg albern an, aber +1 für die anderen Übersetzungen.

Answer (score 0):

Kurz und neutral (wie das englische *add*):

> Nimm mich bitte bei Skype mit dazu.
>
> Ich nehme dich bei Facebook mit dazu.

Comment: ist nicht falsch, jedoch glaube ich kaum dass diese form praktisch benutzt wird, ich habe es jedenfalls noch nie so gehört.

Comment: Ist manchmal fast schon ärgerlich, dass Modewörter wie "adden" sich durchsetzen, obwohl das Deutsche zu "add" seit Jahrhunderten äquivalente, einfache Wörter hat, die sogar noch jeder Rentner versteht...

Comment: naja, um das ein bisschen zu relativieren, ich glaube "adden" wird vor allem in verbindung mit digitalen medien verwendet (facebook, skype etc.). ansonsten findet es wohl eher selten anwendung - jedoch empfinde ich es in diesen fällen als legitim. aber natürlich verstehe ich deinen punkt, es ist schade dass viele ausdrücke so langsam aber sicher von der bildfläche verschwinden...

Answer (score -2):

There is no better word than "adden". People unfamiliar with social networks may not understand the word, but as the alternatives (hinzufügen, aufnehmen, eintragen) are much longer and require a pronoun, it is the best choice.

Comment: Inwiefern ist die Länge von negativer Qualität, und inwiefern ist die Erforderlichkeit eines Pronomen etwas Schlechtes?

Comment: Der kürzere und prägnantere Ausdruck ist in der Regel der bessere. Guter Stil zeichnet sich (in allen Sprachen) durch klare Struktur aus. Ein kurzes Wort ohne Pronomen führt zu einem kürzeren, einfacher strukturierten Satz.

Comment: Das ist Quatsch, wie man leicht daran erkennt, dass sich das geschwätzige "zeitnah" ausbreitet wie die Beulenpest, während es griffigere Begriffe gibt wie "bald, flugs, gleich", die alle kürzer sind.

Comment: In der Schriftsprache hättest du recht, @The_Fritz, daher auch Begrifflichkeiten wie lol, asap, imho. Aber in der gesprochenen Sprache tendieren wir nicht zu Kürzungen.

Comment: @userunknown: Beim (absolut furchtbaren) "zeitnah" geht es aber wohl weniger um die Länge/Kürze, sondern um den Versuch, "hip" zu klingen.

Comment: @Em1: Sicher? Ich hätte eher gesagt, dass wir *gerade* auch in der gesprochenen Sprache zu Kürzungen tendieren, wie alle möglichen Kontraktionen ("'n' Euro", "was für'n Unsinn", "don't", ...) zeigen. Die extreme Zunahme von Akronymen halte ich für eine relativ junge Entwicklung, die wohl primär zur Vermeidung von Daumenüberlastung/-ermüdung dient. Die Tendenz zur Verkürzung findet sich jedenfalls fast überall, oder?

Comment: @Mac: Und wann wird noch das Kürze-Paradigma hinter das hip-Paradigma zurück gestellt? Was ist denn hip an zeitnah? Dass es verwendet wird? Eklektizistische Argumentation würde ich sagen: Wenn das kürzere Wort verwendet wird, dann weil es kürzer ist, wenn das längere verwendet wird, dann weil es hip ist/regnet/Mittwoch ist.

Comment: @userunknown: Ganz richtig, das wäre extrem eklektizistisch :) Mir ging es darum, dass The Fritz im Grundsatz richtig liegt: guter Stil ist oft klar strukturiert, in der Kürze liegt die Würze, etc. Für diese Daumenregel (die wohlgemerkt nicht in Stein gemeißelt ist) lassen sich bestimmt viele gute Gegenbeispiele finden. Die gegenwärtige Beliebtheit von "zeitnah" gehört m.E. nicht dazu. Dieses Wort wird meiner Meinung nach nicht verwendet, weil es länger als "bald", "flugs", "gleich" ist, sondern weil es "professioneller" klingt (sorry für "hip" schlechte Wortwahl meinerseits). Oder?

Comment: Du verstehst mich falsch wenn Du meinst, nur weil ich an die Kürze nicht glaube müßte ich an das Gegenteil glauben. Wenn die Kürze Würze bedeutet bin ich der erste, der für Kürze plädiert. Aber der erste Unterschied der einem zw. 2 Wörtern ist kaum eine Erklärung, wieso man eines verwendet u. das andere nicht. Statt "adden" müßte man sonst "o" sagen, das ist noch kürzer. Nur müßte man zu allem "o" sagen. Oder man müßte wie im Morsealphabet die kürzesten Wörter für die häufigst benutzten Begriffe verwenden. Eine Korrelation dieser Art läßt sich zwar feststellen, aber gerade `adden` ...

Comment: @Mac: ... benutzt man doch eher selten, und es gibt viele Ausnahmen. Man kann also keineswegs von der Kürze eines Wortes darauf schließen, dass es verwendet wird, weil es kürzer ist. Man schreibt so wenig, dass es auf ein paar Zeichen nicht ankommt, und beim Sprechen fällt es noch weniger ins Gewicht. "Klare Struktur" ist aber bei "adden" gerade nicht gegeben, da es Schwierigkeiten beim Beugen/Deklinieren macht. Es ist ein Stolperstein und vor allem eins nicht: Eine Überseztung.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3601/discussion-between-mac-and-user-unknown)